# Adding options to apostrophe-images-widgets directly

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've improved several image widgets by extending 'apostrophe-images-widgets' directly. That may not be the best practice, but I used this since the beginning I've started to code with apostrophe-cms and It worked good. My slide widget for example only uses this lines in index.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-images-widgets',
  piecesModuleName: 'apostrophe-images',
  label: 'Slider Widget'
};
```

Now my widget.html is the following:

```html
<div class="slider fullscreen">
  <ul class="slides">

    {% block items %}

      {% for entry in data.widget._pieces %}
        {% set image = entry.item or entry %}
        {% set relationship = entry.relationship %}

        <li>
          <img
            data-image src="{{ apos.attachments.url(image.attachment, { size: data.options.size or 'full', crop: relationship }) }}"
            srcset="{{ apos.images.srcset(image.attachment) }}"
            sizes="{{ data.options.sizesAttr or '100vw' }}"
            alt="{{ image.title }}"
          >

          <div class="caption {{ image.align }}">

            {% block title %}
              <h3 class="accent-color truncate hide-on-small-only"
                {% if image.titleColor %}
                  style="color:{{ image.titleColor }}"
                {% endif %}
              >
                {{ image.title }}
              </h3>
            {% endblock %}

            {% block description %}
              {% if image.description %}
                <p class="flow-text"
                  {% if image.descriptionColor %}
                    style="color:{{ image.descriptionColor }}"
                  {% endif %}
                >
                  {{ image.description | nlbr }}
                </p>
              {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}

          </div>

          {% block credit %}
            {% if image.credit %}
              <div class="credit">
                {% if image.creditUrl %}
                    <a href="{{ image.creditUrl }}" target="_blank">
                {% endif %}
                      <span>{{ image.credit }}</span>
                {% if image.creditUrl %}
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          {% endblock %}

        </li>

      {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}

  </ul>
</div>
```

**Now my question is how can I add options like `sizesAttr` and `focalPoint: true` etc to my Slider widget?**

As i told above if its possible I don't want to add additional fields like you explained [here](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/core-concepts/working-with-templates/responsive-images.html):

```js
  addFields: [
    {
      name: '_image',
      type: 'joinByOne',
      withType: 'apostrophe-image',
      label: 'Image',
      required: true,
      idField: 'imageId',
      filters: {
        projection: {
          attachment: true,
          description: true,
          title: true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

It would be necessary to rewrite the widget to extend: `apostrope-pieces-widgets` instead `apostrope-images-widgets` and so on. So my idea is to add the desired options directly with `beforeConstruct` unfortunately that hasen't worked so I'm stuck there:

```js
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-images-widgets',
  piecesModuleName: 'apostrophe-images',
  label: 'Slider Widget',
  beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {
    if (options.focalPoint === undefined) {
      options.focalPoint = true;
    }
  }
};
```

Do you have maybe an hint, how I can do this? Maybe there is some example in you code how you added options with `beforeConstruct` or even in html with nujucks with some variables like that `{%- set data.widget.options ... -%}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with two different types of options there, but they are both declared in the same place. `focalPoint` is a built-in option, enabling the focal point UI (which then lets you get focal point information back later) and `sizesAttr` is an example from the documentation of a custom option that you might create for your specific needs.

In both cases, they are passed into the area's widget options *in the page or piece show page template*. So this might be in `default.html` for a "default" page or `show.html` for a piece type's show page like so:

```
{{ apos.area(data.page, 'content', {
  widgets: {
    'image': {
      sizesAttr: '(min-width: 1024px) 50vw, 100vw',
      focalPoint: true
    }
  }
}) }}
```

(`data.page` would be specific to a page, but would be `data.piece` for a piece's *show* page)

Then in the widget templates (your `widget.html`) they're referenced as properties on `data.options` as you can see with `sizesAttr` in your example. You could similarly add any random option like `foo: 'bar'` in the area's widget config, then reference it as `data.options.foo` in the widget template.

`focalPoint` is not as useful to reference directly. As a built-in option, it enables special functionality for the focal point, which is then referenced in templates using methods like `apos.attachments.hasFocalPoint()`. The [documentation has more on that](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/core-concepts/working-with-templates/responsive-images.html#other-ways-to-use-the-focal-point-data).

Comment: To claryfy my question: I don't use any area or singleton for these specific type of widgets. I fear we have a misunderstanding here. I read the documentation you pointed out about 100 times and invested about 1000 h in learning apostrophe. I linked it already in my question above and said that there is no answer in to regarding to my question.

Comment: I figured out now and added my answer for clarification. Anyway thx for the fast reply